Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency user.0001_initial on database 'default'
my project is backend_encommerce, i was create app "products". The first, i use models user default of django is foreignkey for model "ProductComment". Then i define model UserAccount inherit class AbstractUser in app user.
I set in settings file with AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.UserAccount', and i edit model ProductComment again with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL in field user = foreignkey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,...). in the process I have CORS, JWT authen and Auth API configurations.
Last I makemigrations user products, but when I migrate an error occurred "Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency user.0001_initial on database 'default'".
I'm not good at English, so there are a few things in the question that are incorrect. I hope someone can help
I was comment path of admin site but it doesn't effective.
